# Ubuntu 16.04 Slow Start up

Tags: boot, 16.04

I've got 16.04 on an old Acer Aspire i5 430m laptop. It is slow to boot, I've done a completely clean install and it is still quite sluggish.
Reading a few other questions regarding this I have done a dmesg straight after boot and looked for big gaps in the time, there is this:

```
`33.548506] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   33.548508] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483500 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   33.548510] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 200000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   33.548512] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 200000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   33.548514] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm), (0 s)
[   33.548516] cfg80211:   (57000000 KHz - 66000000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[   33.639494] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by c0:3e:0f:b6:50:d9
[   35.629797] hub_port_connect: 42 callbacks suppressed
[   35.629804] usb 1-1-port1: connect-debounce failed
[  182.136548] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  182.136560] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  182.136565] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x5000-0x5fff]
[  182.136573] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xdc700000-0xdc8fffff]
[  182.136578] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xdc900000-0xdcafffff 64bit pref]
[  182.136659] pci_bus 0000:04: Allocating resources
[  182.136673] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[  182.136677] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[  182.136680] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0x5000-0x5fff]`
```

systemd-analyze gives me this:

```
Startup finished in 13.814s (kernel) + 2min 2.754s (userspace) = 2min 16.568s
```

systemd-analyze blame gives me this:

```
1min 49.592s networking.service
    1min 48.973s apport.service
    1min 48.431s grub-common.service
    1min 48.091s irqbalance.service
    1min 47.978s ondemand.service
    1min 47.882s speech-dispatcher.service
    1min 47.864s gpu-manager.service
          5.501s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
          4.077s accounts-daemon.service
          3.548s thermald.service
          3.524s NetworkManager.service
          3.375s ModemManager.service
          3.309s console-setup.service
          3.017s apparmor.service
          1.774s lvm2-monitor.service
          1.758s polkitd.service
          1.708s upower.service
          1.491s systemd-logind.service
          1.472s colord.service
          1.313s systemd-journald.service
          1.167s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          1.136s systemd-modules-load.service
          1.098s keyboard-setup.service
```

I'm not sure what to do. Its up to date and once it gets going it seems to be all OK and not sluggish. Can anyone suggest anything to speed it up?